# My script is timing out. How can I optimize it to run faster

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api

How can I optimize the following script? It is timing out due to probably multiple loops. The loops are in order:

1-Loop through all Google Ads accounts.

2-Loop through all Ad Groups.

3-Within each Ad Group, check if any ads have a "DISAPPROVED" status. If yes, append the data to Google Sheets.

```
  function main() {
  var sheetId = 'XXX';
  var sheetName = 'XXX';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  } else {

    // Clear the existing contents
    sheet.clearContents();
  }

  // Adding headers (column names) 
  var headers = ['Account Name', 'Campaign', 'Ad Group'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers); 

  // Iterating through each client account
  var accountIterator = AdsManagerApp.accounts().get();
  while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
    var account = accountIterator.next();
    AdsManagerApp.select(account);

    var adGroupIterator = AdsApp.adGroups()
        .withCondition('CampaignStatus = ENABLED')
        .withCondition('AdGroupStatus = ENABLED')
        .get();

    while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
      var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();

      // Check if the ad group has any disapproved ads
      var disapprovedAdFound = false;
      var adIterator = adGroup.ads().get();
      while (adIterator.hasNext()) {
        var ad = adIterator.next();
        if (ad.getPolicyApprovalStatus() === 'DISAPPROVED') {
          disapprovedAdFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (disapprovedAdFound) { // Disapproved ads found
        // Record the details of the ad group with disapproved ads
        sheet.appendRow([
          account.getName(),
          adGroup.getCampaign().getName(),
          adGroup.getName()
        ]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is a direct solution to your current issue, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, in order to put values, `appendRow` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost becomes high. [Ref (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/d102c9600ba12a162c667287d2f20fe4) In this answer, I modified `appendRow` to `setValues`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function main() {
  var sheetId = 'XXX';
  var sheetName = 'XXX';
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  if (!sheet) {
    sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(sheetName);
  } else {

    // Clear the existing contents
    sheet.clearContents();
  }

  // Adding headers (column names) 
  var headers = ['Account Name', 'Campaign', 'Ad Group'];
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  var values = []; // Added

  // Iterating through each client account
  var accountIterator = AdsManagerApp.accounts().get();
  while (accountIterator.hasNext()) {
    var account = accountIterator.next();
    AdsManagerApp.select(account);

    var adGroupIterator = AdsApp.adGroups()
      .withCondition('CampaignStatus = ENABLED')
      .withCondition('AdGroupStatus = ENABLED')
      .get();

    while (adGroupIterator.hasNext()) {
      var adGroup = adGroupIterator.next();

      // Check if the ad group has any disapproved ads
      var disapprovedAdFound = false;
      var adIterator = adGroup.ads().get();
      while (adIterator.hasNext()) {
        var ad = adIterator.next();
        if (ad.getPolicyApprovalStatus() === 'DISAPPROVED') {
          disapprovedAdFound = true;
          break;
        }
      }

      if (disapprovedAdFound) { // Disapproved ads found
        // Record the details of the ad group with disapproved ads

        // Modified
        values.push([
          account.getName(),
          adGroup.getCampaign().getName(),
          adGroup.getName()
        ]);

      }
    }
  }

  // Added
  if (values.length == 0) return;
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

When this script is run, the retrieved values are put with `setValues`.

Although I'm not sure about your actual situation, if the length of `values` is large, please test using Sheets API. At that time, please modify the above script as follows. When you use Sheets API, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

- From

  ```
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  ```
- To

  ```
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update({ values }, sheetId, `'${sheetName}'!A${sheet.getLastRow() + 1}`, { valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED" });
  ```

#### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that you have already had the correct value of `[account.getName(),adGroup.getCampaign().getName(),adGroup.getName()]` in your script. Please be careful about this.